# Ambiguous [code-review] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review) has two interpretations:

- One is the code-review of versioning tools or systems like SVN or GIT
- Second is the actual code-review of source code

The tag summary says that:

> Code review is systematic examination (often as peer review) of
>   computer source code. It is intended to find and fix mistakes
>   overlooked in the initial development phase, improving both the
>   overall quality of software and the developers' skills.

Now AFAIK the summary types of questions are not good for SO and are migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com

There are some questions which are used with [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) [git](/questions/tagged/git) and some that want actual review of code.

So what should be done?

Comment: I think [tag:svn] and [tag:git] should come under [tag:version-control] or something similar. At first glance, code-review says to me: "please check my code"

Comment: Yes I second that. Also if that is the case with code-review what is this tag doing on SO. It should be removed.

Comment: Should we start flagging [tag:code-review] questions?

Comment: @danielhanly.com Some are off topic and belong on [codereview.se] (these can be flagged), some just need to have the [tag:code-review] tag removed (these can just be edited) and some are 'please debug my code for me' (**NOT** appropriate for [codereview.se], these can probably be flagged for some other reason). As long as you know what belongs where, feel free to run with it.

Comment: Okay. So what about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322791/tfs-code-reviews-show-updated-files-in-response-to-comments

Comment: @danielhanly.com Questions about *conducting* code reviews does not belong on either Code Review or SO. *Possibly* on Programmers, if anything (I haven't been on Programmers much though so I wouldn't "send it" there without talking to someone who knows that site better first).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code-review tag seems to have already been burninated from Meta SE making this no longer reproducible